GAM predictors structure: matrix vs long data.frame format
I am fitting a typical GAM with lagged structure. The gam has the general form:
g1<-gam(y~te(e, l), data=df)

Specifically:
#exposure
e <- matrix(rnorm(2500, mean = 100, sd = 25), ncol=50)

#lag
l<-matrix(rep(seq(49,0),50), ncol = 50, byrow=T)

#reponse y as sum of the exposures "e" weighted by lag (basically what the GAM shoud 
  estimate)
we<-matrix(sample(seq(0.01, 0.5, 0.02),2500, replace = T), ncol = 50, byrow=T)#random weights
ex<-e*we #weighted exposures by lag

df<-data.frame(y=apply(ex, 1, FUN = sum))#response

The above code produce a simple set of exposure-lag combination of  for each specific response "y" and the data are organized as suggested in the S. Wood book: "Generalized Additive Models: an introduction in R. The above GAM (g1) has the following outputs:
enter code here

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ te(e, l)

Parametric coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1267.97      12.63   100.4   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
      edf Ref.df     F p-value   
te(e,l) 2.605  3.054 4.808 0.00512 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Rank: 24/25
R-sq.(adj) =  0.208   Deviance explained =   25%
GCV =   8595  Scale est. = 7975.3    n = 50}

Regardless of the result obtained, I was wondering why organizing the data in a long data.frame format produce different results:
df<-data.frame(l=rep(seq(0,49),each=50), e=c(e[,seq(50,1)]), y=rep(y$y, 50))
##GAM output
Formula:
y ~ te(e, l)

Parametric coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1267.966      1.984   639.2   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
     edf Ref.df     F p-value  
te(e,l) 4.11  4.848 2.215  0.0448 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.00337   Deviance explained = 0.501%
GCV = 9858.2  Scale est. = 9838.1    n = 2500

Apologies if the question might be basic, but I will be really happy to get some feedback and references to better understand this point. Thanks

Using a matrix invokes a summation convention over the smooths. This summation doesn't happen when you just pass vectors to smooths.
The model with a matrix covariate is
$$
g(\mu_i) = \sum_j l_{ij} f(x_{ij})
$$
while the model for the long, vector version is
$$
g(\mu_i) = f(x_{i}, l_{i})
$$
which indicates the difference. In the first, the expected value of the response on the link scale is the sum over a set of smooths, one per lag. In the second, the same expected value depends on the value of $x_{i}$ and the value of $l_{i}$, the lag for the $i$th value.
I suppose you could sum the contributions from $f(x_{i}, l_{i})$ over the lags for the long model, but you'd be doing that manually.

Thanks a lot for your response. So, is it the contribution of each lag in the long model stored in the GAM object? Thanks

Sorry, I guess also the same summation happen in case the tensor has 3 matrices; e.g.: te(e, l1, l2), where l1 and l2 are 2 different lags specifications referring to e. Is that correct? many Thanks
